# What is the term for a list of interviews?

Tags: phd, citations

If 'bibliography' is a list of literature and 'discography' is a list of musical recordings, is there a term for a list of interviews?

Of course I could just cite everything under 'references' but my research is varied and covers many different media, and it would be good to know the term for a list of interviews [of course, I could just write "interviews" but I would prefer to know the proper term if there is one].

Comment: Is this you interviewing someone, or different people interviewing you?  What is the result of the "interview"?  Are they published?

Comment: This question might fit better on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ScottSeidman it's my interviewing others. Some are published, some are not.

Comment: Your "appointments" comes to mind... ie an appointment list per interviewer...

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) – just write _Interviews_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how they call a list of interviews, but in practical terms, I would simply use "Interviews" as heading for the relevant section. I've seen this quite frequently.